# view component data input validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, bootstrap-4

I've been trying to play around with view components in ASP.NET Core to create a more "widget" based system.  What I currently have is a contact form that opens a modal dialog and displays a view component based on the selection they make.  For simplicity sake, I invoke the viewcomponent as follows from my layout page (yes I'm not using the vc: convention atm):

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Inquiry")
```

It will then invoke the inquiry form through here:

```
public class InquiryViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly ILogger<InquiryViewComponent> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceRepository _serviceRepository;

    public InquiryViewComponent(ILogger<InquiryViewComponent> logger, IServiceRepository serviceRepository)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceRepository = serviceRepository;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        // do stuff here like create a backing model and then return the view
        return await Task.FromResult(View("~/Views/Inquiry/Inquiry.cshtml", _viewModel));
    }
}
```

Everything loads correctly and the modal dialog opens (have a script to invoke the modal on open) with the following:

```
@model InquiryViewModel

 //modal initialization here
 //modal header here

@using (Html.BeginForm("Inquiry", "Inquiry"))
{
<div class="modal-body">        
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mb-2">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Inquire.FirstName, new { @class = "required" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Inquire.FirstName, new { @class="form-control", autocomplete="given-name", required="required" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Inquire.LastName, new { @class = "required" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Inquire.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "family-name", required = "required" })
            </div>
        </div>
        //OTHER FIELDS HERE
</div>
//FOOTER
}
```

Once the user submits, if the model is invalidated, it posts back to the view Inquiry which I don't want. I do understand that it is trying to return the page on the form (I can see where this is happening).  I also understand I could use client-side validation but I'm aiming to build more complex widgets and don't want a pile of JavaScript code.  What I want to know: if I have a form based view component and it needs model validation from the server, can I have it return the result WITHOUT rendering the page? Is this implementation just completely incorrect for view components and what other ways are more suitable?